# Custom layer control with leaflet

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, leaflet, layer

I want to make a custom layer control with leaflet but I have no idea why it isn't working. I get the following error in Firebug when i click the checkbox: `TypeError: obj is undefined`. I added this code to my main.js script:

```
// Custom layerpanel -- WORK IN PROGRESS!

    $( "input" ).click(function( event ) {
        layerClicked = window[event.target.value];

            if (map.hasLayer(layerClicked)) {
                map.removeLayer(layerClicked);
            }
            else{
                map.addLayer(layerClicked);
            } ;
    });
```

and this to my index file:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="mapDataLayer" checked>
   Option 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables set through `var myVarName` are not accessible as properties of `window` object (`window[event.target.value]`). You have to assigned your layer in a similar way: `window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(...)`

Notes:

- Your GeoJSON layer has 0 feature, so you will not see anything new.
- Your checkbox is initially checked but the layer is not on map. Therefore, the layer is added onto the map when the checkbox is unchecked, and vice versa.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it works. The only thing is that when i do an advanced search i have to double click teh submit button for layer control to work again.

Comment: Ghybs the admin deleted the plunker. Thank for you'r help.